# nodejs project build through jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Hi Iam new to nodejs projects.

I am building a cicd pipeline for jenkins. I configured git and in build section iam using npm install for build in jenkins.

The build shows success bot no node_modules or target getting generated. Below message shows package.jsonis missing but that is my jenkins workspace.

This is my error:

```
npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test2/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test2/package.json'
npm WARN test2 No description
npm WARN test2 No repository field.
npm WARN test2 No README data
npm WARN test2 No license field.

up to date in 0.061s
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: is your ```package.json``` exist or not ? i'm guessing your ```package.json``` is missing

Answer (score 0):

Please check if package.json file is present in folder /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test2/